# Trying to make link with user id in joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I'm trying to add button with link to a seller store in my joomla component and I have no idea how can I do it.
I'm adding code from php file that has what I need but I don't know how to add it on another page. If someone can guide me with some how to step it would be awesome.
Here is the page that has the link to the store:

```
<?php

// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

use Joomla\Registry\Registry;

/** @var SellaciousViewProduct $this */
$sellers = $this->item->get('sellers');

if (!isset($sellers[0]) || (count($sellers) == 1 && $sellers[0]->seller_uid == $this->item->get('seller_uid')))
{
    return;
}

$c_currency = $this->helper->currency->current('code_3');
?>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<a name="also-selling">&nbsp;</a>
<hr class="isolate"/>
<h4 class="center"><?php echo JText::_('COM_SELLACIOUS_PRODUCT_HEADING_BLOCK_SELLERS'); ?></h4>

<table class="product-sellers table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>SELLER       </th>
        <th>DELIVERY INFO</th>
        <th>PRICE        </th>
        <th>ACTION       </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    foreach ($sellers as $i => $seller)
    {
        /** @var Registry $item */
        $item       = new Registry($seller);
        $s_currency = $this->helper->currency->forSeller($item->get('seller_uid'), 'code_3');

        // todo: Add this to config (show current one or not in more sellers) and move to model
        if ($item->get('seller_uid') == $this->item->get('seller_uid'))
        {
            continue;
        }
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 220px;" class="nowrap">
                <div class="seller-info">
                    <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_sellacious&view=store&id=' . $item->get('seller_uid')); ?>">
                        <?php echo $item->get('seller_company', $item->get('seller_name')); ?></a>
                    <?php $rating = $item->get('seller_rating.rating'); ?>
                    <span class="label <?php echo ($rating < 3) ? 'label-warning' : 'label-success' ?>"><?php echo number_format($rating, 1) ?> / 5.0</span>
                </div>

                <?php if ($item->get('exchange_days')): ?>
                    <?php if ($item->get('exchange_tnc')):
                        $options = array(
                            'title'    => '<strong>' . (int) $item->get('exchange_days') . ' Days</strong> Replacement Guarantee',
                            'backdrop' => 'static',
                        );
                        echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.renderModal', 'exchange_tnc-' . $item->get('code'), $options, $item->get('exchange_tnc'));
                    endif; ?>
                    <div class="replacement-info">
                        <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>
                        <strong> <?php echo (int) $item->get('exchange_days') ?> Days</strong> Replacement
                        <?php if ($item->get('exchange_tnc')): ?>
                            <a href="#exchange_tnc-<?php echo $item->get('code') ?>" role="button" data-toggle="modal">[<i class="fa fa-question"></i>]</a>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if ($item->get('return_days')): ?>
                    <?php if ($item->get('return_tnc')):
                        $options = array(
                            'title'    => '<strong>' . (int) $item->get('return_days') . ' Days</strong> Easy Return',
                            'backdrop' => 'static',
                        );
                        echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.renderModal', 'return_tnc-' . $item->get('code'), $options, $item->get('return_tnc'));
                    endif; ?>
                    <div class="replacement-info">
                        <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>
                        <strong> <?php echo (int) $item->get('return_days') ?> Days</strong> Easy Return
                        <?php if ($item->get('return_tnc')): ?>
                            <a href="#return_tnc-<?php echo $item->get('code') ?>" role="button" data-toggle="modal">[<i class="fa fa-question"></i>]</a>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <div>
                    <?php $allowed_listing_type = (array) $this->helper->config->get('allowed_listing_type'); ?>
                    <?php if (count($allowed_listing_type) != 1): ?>
                    <span class="label label-info margin-top-10">Condition:
                        <?php
                        $list_type = $item->get('listing_type');

                        // What if this is a not allowed listing type value
                        if ($list_type == 1):
                            echo JText::plural('COM_SELLACIOUS_PRODUCT_FIELD_LISTING_TYPE_VALUE', $list_type);
                        else:
                            $list_cond = $item->get('item_condition');
                            echo JText::plural('COM_SELLACIOUS_PRODUCT_FIELD_ITEM_CONDITION_VALUE', $list_type * 10 + (int) $list_cond);
                        endif;
                        ?>
                    </span>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="delivery-info">
                    <?php echo JHtml::_('date', '+ ' . rand(1, 30) . ' days', 'D, dS F'); ?>
                    <br>
                    <small><?php
                        $flat_ship = $item->get('flat_shipping');
                        $ship_fee  = $item->get('shipping_flat_fee');

                        if ($flat_ship == 0)
                        {
                            echo JText::_('COM_SELLACIOUS_PRODUCT_SHIPPING_FEE_IN_CART');
                        }
                        elseif (round($ship_fee, 2) > 0)
                        {
                            $fee = $this->helper->currency->display($ship_fee, $s_currency, $c_currency, true);
                            echo JText::sprintf('COM_SELLACIOUS_PRODUCT_SHIPPING_FEE_FLAT', $fee);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo JText::_('COM_SELLACIOUS_PRODUCT_SHIPPING_FEE_FREE');
                        }
                    ?></small>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="width:90px;" class="center">
                <span class="product-price-sm"><?php
                    echo $this->helper->currency->display($item->get('price.sales_price'), $s_currency, $c_currency, true) ?></span>
            </td>
            <td style="width:100px;" class="nowrap">
                <?php $link = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_sellacious&view=product&p=' . $item->get('code')); ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $link ?>"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-cart-sm">DETAILS</button></a><br/>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-cart-sm btn-add-cart" data-item="<?php echo $item->get('code') ?>">ДОБАВИ В КОЛИЧКАТА</button>
                <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-cart-sm btn-add-cart"
                            data-item="<?php /*echo $item->get('code') */?>" data-checkout="true">КУПИ СЕГА</button>-->
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And this is the file I'm trying to import the part with the link to the sellers store

```
<?php

// no direct access.
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

jimport('sellacious.loader');

if (class_exists('SellaciousHelper'))
{
    $helper = SellaciousHelper::getInstance();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" dir="<?php echo $this->direction; ?>">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

        <!-- favicon -->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="templates/sellacious/images/favicon/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
        <link rel="icon" href="templates/sellacious/images/favicon/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

        <?php
        $user     = JFactory::getUser();
        $doc      = JFactory::getDocument();
        $app      = JFactory::getApplication();
        $sitename = $app->get('sitename');

        JHtml::_('script', 'media/com_sellacious/js/plugin/messagebox/jquery.messagebox.min.js', false, false);
        JHtml::_('stylesheet', 'media/com_sellacious/js/plugin/messagebox/jquery.messagebox.css', null, false);

        $doc->addStyleSheet('//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,700italic,300,400,700');
        $doc->addStyleSheet('templates/sellacious/css/bootstrap.min.css', 'text/css', 'screen');
        $doc->addStyleSheet('templates/sellacious/css/font-awesome.min.css', 'text/css', 'screen');
        $doc->addStyleSheet('templates/sellacious/css/joomla-icons.css', 'text/css', 'screen');

        $doc->addStyleSheet('templates/sellacious/css/smartadmin-production.css', 'text/css', 'screen');
        $doc->addStyleSheet('templates/sellacious/css/smartadmin-skins.css', 'text/css', 'screen');
        $doc->addStyleSheet('templates/sellacious/css/custom-style.css', 'text/css', 'screen');

        if ($this->direction == 'rtl')
        {
            $doc->addStyleSheet('templates/sellacious/css/smartadmin-rtl.css', 'text/css', 'screen');
        }

        JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
        JHtml::_('bootstrap.tooltip');

        $doc->addScript('templates/sellacious/js/libs/jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js');                     // jQuery UI full, not from joomla core's minimised one
        $doc->addScript('templates/sellacious/js/plugin/fastclick/fastclick.js');                    // FastClick: For mobile devices
        $doc->addScript('templates/sellacious/js/plugin/jquery-touch/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js'); // JS TOUCH plugin for mobile drag-drop touch events
        $doc->addScript('templates/sellacious/js/plugin/msie-fix/jquery.mb.browser.min.js');         // browser msie issue fix
        $doc->addScript('templates/sellacious/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js');                       // Bootstrap JS
        $doc->addScript('templates/sellacious/js/notification/SmartNotification.min.js');            // Custom notification
        $doc->addScript('templates/sellacious/js/plugin/cookie/jquery.cookie.min.js');               // cookie
        $doc->addScript('templates/sellacious/js/sellacious-core.js');                               // Sellacious core functions to work template wide
        $doc->addScript('templates/sellacious/js/sellacious-notifier.js');                           // Sellacious notification per view page
        ?>

        <script data-pace-options='{ "restartOnRequestAfter": true }' src="templates/sellacious/js/plugin/pace/pace.min.js"></script>

        <jdoc:include type="head"/>

        <!--[if IE 7]>
        <h1>Your browser is out of date, please update your browser by going to www.microsoft.com/download</h1>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>

    <?php $collapse = $app->input->cookie->get('collapsedmenu'); ?>
    <body class="fixed-page-footer <?php echo $app->input->get('hidemainmenu') || $collapse ? 'minified' : '' ?>"><!--
     The possible classes: smart-style-3, minified, fixed-ribbon, fixed-header, fixed-width -->

        <!-- HEADER -->
        <header id="header" class="btn-group-justified">
            <div id="logo-group">
                <?php
                $logo = 'templates/sellacious/images/logo.png';

                if (isset($helper) && $helper->access->isSubscribed()):
                    $altLogo = $helper->media->getImage('config.backoffice_logo', 1, false);
                    $logo    = $altLogo ?: $logo;
                endif;
                ?>
                <span id="logo"><a class="pull-left" href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php') ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo $logo ?>" alt="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($sitename) ?>"></a></span>

                <?php if ($this->countModules('logo-group')) { ?>
                    <!-- OPTIMAL PLACE FOR NOTIFICATION MODULE -->
                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="logo-group" style="none"/>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>

            <?php if ($this->countModules('header-left')) { ?>
                <!-- Project Context -->
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="header-left" style="none"/>
            <?php } ?>

            <!-- pulled right: nav area -->
            <div class="pull-right" style="margin-right: 1px;">
                <!-- logout button -->
                <div id="logout" class="btn-header transparent pull-right cursor-pointer">
                    <?php $logout_url = 'index.php?option=com_login&task=logout&' . JSession::getFormToken() . '=1'; ?>
                    <span> <a href="<?php echo $logout_url ?>" title="Sign Out" data-action="userLogout" class="hasTooltip" data-placement="bottom"
                            data-logout-msg="You can improve your security further after logging out by closing this opened browser"><i
                                class="fa fa-sign-out"></i></a> </span>
                </div>
                <!-- end logout button -->

                <!-- fullscreen button -->
                <div id="fullscreen" class="btn-header transparent pull-right">
                    <span> <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-action="launchFullscreen" class="hasTooltip" data-placement="bottom"
                                title="Full Screen"><i class="fa fa-arrows-alt"></i></a> </span>
                </div>
                <!-- end fullscreen button -->

                <!-- back to Joomla administrator button -->
                 <div id="my-tore" class="btn-header transparent pull-right cursor-pointer">
                    <span> <a href="../<?php echo basename(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR); ?>/index.php" class="hasTooltip" data-placement="bottom"
                              title="Back to Joomla Administrator"><i class="fa fa-joomla"></i></a> </span>
                </div>
                <!-- end back to Joomla administrator button -->

                <!-- Go to Joomla frontend button -->
                <div id="joomla" class="btn-header transparent pull-right cursor-pointer">
                    <span> <a href="../index.php" target="_blank" class="hasTooltip" data-placement="bottom"
                                title="View Site"><i class="fa fa-external-link"></i></a> </span>
                </div>
                <!-- end Go to Joomla frontend button -->

                <!-- Go to Joomla frontend button -->
                <div id="hide-menu" class="btn-header transparent pull-right cursor-pointer">
                    <span> <a href="#" class="hasTooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-menu="hidemenu"
                                title="Menu"><i class="fa fa-reorder"></i></a> </span>
                </div>
                <!-- end Go to Joomla frontend button -->

                <!-- Sync media button -->
                <div id="sync-media" class="btn-header transparent pull-right cursor-pointer">
                    <span> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="hasTooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-action="sync-media" style="width: 135px;"
                                title="Refresh Media Uploads"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> <span class="text-normal"> <?php
                                echo JText::_('COM_SELLACIOUS_MEDIA_SYNC_BUTTON_LABEL') ?> </span></a> </span>
                </div>
                <!-- end Sync media button -->

                <?php if ($this->countModules('header-right')): ?>
                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="header-right" style="none"/>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <!-- end pulled right: nav area -->

            <?php if (isset($helper) && ($helper->access->check('config.edit') || !$helper->access->isSubscribed())): ?>
                <div id="context-news" class="pull-right padding-5"><!-- dynamic news --></div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </header>
        <!-- END HEADER -->

        <!-- Left panel : Navigation area -->
        <?php if ($this->countModules('left-panel') || $this->countModules('menu')) { ?>
        <!-- Note: This width of the aside area can be adjusted through LESS variables -->
        <aside id="left-panel">
            <div class="login-info">
                <span> <!-- User image size is adjusted inside CSS, it should stay as it -->
                    <a style="cursor:auto;" id="show-shortcut" data-action="toggleShortcut" href="index.php?option=com_sellacious&view=profile">
                        <!--<img src="templates/sellacious/images/avatars/male.png" alt="me" class="online"/>-->
                        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                        <span><?php echo $user->get('name'); ?></span>
                    </a>
                </span>
            </div>

            <!-- User info -->
            <?php if ($this->countModules('left-panel')) { ?>
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="left-panel" style="none"/>
            <?php } ?>
            <!-- end user info -->

            <!-- NAVIGATION : This navigation is also responsive
            To make this navigation dynamic please make sure to link the node
            (the reference to the nav > ul) after page load. Or the navigation will not initialize.
            -->

            <!-- User info -->
            <?php if ($this->countModules('menu')) { ?>
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="menu" style="none"/>
            <?php } ?>
            <!-- end user info -->

            <span class="minifyme"> <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left hit"></i> </span>

        </aside>
        <!-- END NAVIGATION -->
        <?php } ?>
        <!-- End Left panel : Navigation area -->

        <!-- MAIN PANEL -->
        <div id="main" role="main">

            <!-- RIBBON -->
            <div id="ribbon">

                <!-- breadcrumb -->
                <?php if ($this->countModules('ribbon-left')) { ?>
                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="ribbon-left" style="none"/>
                <?php } ?>
                <!-- end breadcrumb -->

                <?php if ($this->countModules('ribbon-right')) { ?>
                <span class="ribbon-button-alignment pull-right">
                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="ribbon-right" style="none"/>
                </span>
                <?php } ?>
                <div class="btn-headactions pull-right">
                    <a href="http://sellacious.com/documentation.html" target="_blank" title="Document" class="primary"><i class="fa fa-book"></i> Documentation</a>
                    <a href="http://sellacious.com/community-support.html" target="_blank" title="Forum"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> Support</a>
                    <a href="https://extensions.joomla.org/write-review/review/add?extension_id=11448" target="_blank" title="More info"><i class="fa fa-star"></i> Rate us on JED</a>
                </div>

            </div>
            <!-- END RIBBON -->

            <?php if ($this->countModules('toolbar') || $this->countModules('title')) : ?>
                <div class="box-toolbar">
                    <div class="">
                        <!-- col -->
                        <div class="pull-left">
                            <!-- PAGE HEADER -->
                            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="title"/>
                        </div>
                        <!-- end col -->

                        <!-- right side of the page with the sparkline graphs -->
                        <!-- col -->
                        <div class="pull-right">
                            <?php if ($this->countModules('toolbar')) : ?>
                                <span class="pull-right">
                                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="toolbar" style="none"/>
                                </span>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                        <!-- end col -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ($this->countModules('top')) : ?>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="content-top" style="xhtml"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ($this->countModules('submenu')) : ?>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="submenu" style="none"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <div class="clearfix"></div>

            <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
            <div id="content">

                <?php if ($this->countModules('content-top')) { ?>
                    <div class="row">
                        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="content-top" style="none"/>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>

                <div class="clearfix"></div>

                <div class="component content-wrap">

                    <div id="system-message-container"><jdoc:include type="message" style="xhtml"/></div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>

                    <jdoc:include type="component" style="xhtml"/>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>

                <?php if ($this->countModules('content-bottom')) { ?>
                    <div class="row">
                        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="content-bottom" style="none"/>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>

            </div>

            <div class="clearfix"></div>

            <!-- END MAIN CONTENT -->

        </div>
        <!-- END MAIN PANEL -->

    <?php if ($this->countModules('footer')) { ?>
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="footer" style="none"/>
    <?php } ?>

        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="dynamic" style="xhtml"/>

        <!-- Google Analytics code below -->
        <?php if ($ga_code = $this->params->get('ga_code')) { ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var _gaq = _gaq || [];
                _gaq.push(['_setAccount', '<?php echo htmlspecialchars($ga_code) ?>']);
                _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

                (function() {
                    var ga = document.createElement('script');
                    ga.type = 'text/javascript';
                    ga.async = true;
                    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
                    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                    s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
                })();
            </script>
        <?php } ?>

    </body>

</html>
```

I understand that I need this link,

```
<a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_sellacious&view=store&id=' . $item->get('seller_uid')); ?>">
                        <?php echo $item->get('seller_company', $item->get('seller_name')); ?></a>
```

but don't know how to implement it in the second file.

Answer (score 0):

You need access to the view object from the sellacious product view in your file (i.e. the **this** in `$sellers = **$this**->item->get('sellers')`). Your file is a template file, and templates don't have access to the component view object - it's already been marked for garbage collection by the time the template renders. If you are only rendering the sellacious store links on pages that include the sellacious component, you could copy and store the data in JRegistry to use in the template. You could do this in a layout override from your template (layouts have access to their component's view object). If it's for use in your custom component or other components, you'd need to write model logic to pull the information from the database. In that case, I'd look at how the sellacious model is doing it and copy just the parts you need.

Comment: Thank you for the answer(i can't upvote yet)!  I suppose I'll need some more backend knowledge just to render a link in joomla :D.

Comment: Unfortunately true in your case, but it's pretty easy. The Joomla site has good docs on how to develop a custom component. You'll see how the view object works if you work through that tutorial. You can pass data around between different parts of your application using JRegistry. Good luck!